# How to extract in between base64 text from a file with grep's regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have the following content:

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "TXlQYXNzd29yZA=="
                }
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce (linux)"
        }
}
```

I need to extract `"TXlQYXNzd29yZA=="` with grep and decode it.
For decoding I can use `base64 -d` (`echo TXlQYXNzd29yZA== | base64 -d`) but I don't know how to extract the exact line.
With sublime I almost succeed to catch it with:

```
(?!\"auth\": ) "(.*)"
```

I got `" TXlQYXNzd29yZA=="`, not perfect because of the space in the beginning.
Anyway, I found that sublime regex is different from grep's regex.
I tried to use these web tools:
http://www.ericagamet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Erica-Gamets-GREP-Cheat-Sheet.pdf
https://regex101.com/

But I am not suceeding.

I found that `grep 'auth":'` gives me:

```
                "auth": "TXlQYXNzd29yZA=="
```

Seems to be a good start.
I tried also `grep '(?!auth":)'` or `grep '(?!auth":) (.*)'`, nothing happen.

Comment: Your input looks a lot like JSON. If that's the case, use the proper tool. `jq` is more suited than `grep` here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a real json parser like jq instead of grep.

```
$ jq -r '.auths | .[] | .auth' /path/to/file
```

Comment: I used it a little different `cat .docker/config.json | jq -r '.auths | .[] | .auth' | base64 -d`. It did the works, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

with look behind

```
$ grep -oP '(?<="auth": ")[^"]+' file | base64 -d

MyPassword
```

or if your `grep` doesn't support `-P` option

```
$ sed -nr 's/.*"auth": "([^"]+)"/\1/p' | base64 -d
```